# how to convert all the images of an array to data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert images in an array to NSData so that it can be passed to another view controller by segue method

i have tried successfully to convert single images to NSData by NSDataRepresentation method. but while trying to do so for the asset images am finding it difficult to access the images of the array. for now I'm able to access either the 1st or the last image of the array but need all the images for conversion.

```
@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let imageData_1 : NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photoArray.last!)! as NSData
    photoImageData.append(imageData_1)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toBodyViewPage", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: it appears you use old version of swift does it compile with your xcode ? BTW it's better if not now mandatory to update

Comment: Why do you even need to convert the images, can't you pass them directly or a path to them? Why NSData and not `Data`, like `photoArray.last.pngData()`? And what exactly is the problem with working with your `photoArray` to access all elements?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how do i access all the elements. I can only access the first and the last elements of the array. Also it's not been long i have played with swift code.

Comment: You use a `for` loop, `for item in photoArray { let data = item.pngData() ...}`

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
@Action func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
   photoImageData = photoArray.compactMap { UIImagePNGRepresentation($0) }
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "toBodyViewPage", sender: self)
}
```

For xcode 10 + & swift 4.2

```
photoImageData = photoArray.compactMap {  $0.pngData() }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with the answer : Value of type '[UIImage]' has no member 'compactMap'

Comment: share declaration of `photoArray` and your latest try

Comment: i use 4.0 swift and flatMap is depreciated  to compactMap.

Comment: var photoArray = [UIImage]()
    var photoImageData = [NSData]()

Comment: 'flatMap' produces '[String]', not the expected contextual result type '[NSData]'                 this is what i get after using flatMap for compactMap

Comment: change `var photoImageData = [Data]() ` and try ?